# Finding all the invariant subspaces of a certain linear transformation.

Tags: linear-algebra, affine-geometry

Assuming I have given affine transformation $ \mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3 $ which has matrix representation
$$
\left[\begin{array}{cccc}
3&2&-3&-10\\
4&10&-12&-29\\
3&6&-7&-26\\
0&0&0&1
\end{array}\right],
$$
and it has Jordan form $\left[\begin{array}{cccc}1&0&0&0\\0&2&0&0\\0&0&2&1\\0&0&0&2\end{array}\right]$ then how do I find all invariant affine subspaces ? assuming eigenvectors are $v_1,..v_4$.

Comment: You can start with eigenpaces. I mean, eigenspaces are invariant subspaces.

Comment: Ok but will it be all possibilites ?

Comment: Not always, let me think some more.